# Echoing the value of "Origin" for CORS instead of using "*"?

Tags: cors

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS),

> when responding to a credentialed request,  server must specify a
>   domain, and cannot use wild carding.

So I cannot simply use `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. However, I'm wondering if there is a reason not to simply use: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ${request.headers["Origin"]}`, i.e., always set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to whatever `Origin` was set to in the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't.

It has been discussed (rather indirectly) in this thread : [Access-Control-Allow-Origin Multiple Origin Domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains/1850482#1850482)

In your case, your list of domains are all domains, which means no matter what the request originates from, it is in your 'list of domains'.